# psycopg2 sql error: SQL.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Why am I getting the error:
`SQL.__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` for this call?

```
cur.execute(sql.SQL('INSERT INTO {table} (time_stamp,surf_1,height_1,period_1,dir_1,surf_2,height_2,period_2, \
    dir_2,sea_height,sea_period,sea_direction,chop_height,chop_direction) \
 VALUES (%s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',  \
 (df.index[0],df.iloc[0][0],df.iloc[0][1],df.iloc[0][2],df.iloc[0][3],df.iloc[0][4],df.iloc[0][5],df.iloc[0][6], \
    df.iloc[0][7],df.iloc[0][8],df.iloc[0][9],df.iloc[0][10],df.iloc[0][11],df.iloc[0][12])).format(
    table=sql.Identifier(str(plot_buoy))))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, should the ```,``` be a ```%``` as in ```..., %s)', ``` -> ```..., %s)' % ...```?

Comment: Thanks @ewokx, I tried that but got a weird error.  I posted my own answer, maybe it's good enough?!

Answer (score 0):

I had the formatting part out of order.  So, the formatting in the `sql.SQL(...)` block should happen before the arguments are passed to the input string.  Like so:

```
cur.execute(sql.SQL('INSERT INTO {table} (time_stamp,surf_1,height_1,period_1,dir_1,surf_2,height_2,period_2, \
    dir_2,sea_height,sea_period,sea_direction,chop_height,chop_direction) \
    VALUES (%s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);').format( \
    table=sql.Identifier(str(plot_buoy))),  \
    (df.index[0],df.iloc[0][0],df.iloc[0][1],df.iloc[0][2],df.iloc[0][3],df.iloc[0][4],df.iloc[0][5],df.iloc[0][6], \
    df.iloc[0][7],df.iloc[0][8],df.iloc[0][9],df.iloc[0][10],df.iloc[0][11],df.iloc[0][12]))
```

Comment: Why not simplify and use a straight `execute` without the `sql.SQL` per [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)? I am not seeing the point of doing dynamic table naming in this case.